# Unable to test code requiring CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE / WRITE_SETTINGS permission on Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-espresso

I am trying to upgrade my app's targetSDK to above 23 and I've run into a small problem. I have an activity that binds traffic to Wifi (to measure the network speed to the router, even if the router is not connected to the internet). In order for that to happen my app needs the `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE` permission. That permission is usually granted directly if declared in the manifest. On Android 6.0 (exact, this was fixed in 6.0.1 IIRC) `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE` is broken and won't be granted so you need the `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission instead. I've implemented a way for Android 6.0 Users to grant that permission but when I want to test my Activity using espresso I am unable to do so. Permissions are granted to tests by adding something like

`@Rule
    public GrantPermissionRule runtimePermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(Manifest.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE);`

to the TestCase. That worked in other places in the app but for this I get
`junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Failed to grant permissions, see logcat for details` in my test results. In logcat I find `E/GrantPermissionCallable: Permission: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS cannot be granted!` or the same with `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE`, I've tried granting both and they both don't work. Is there any other way for me to grant the permission in the testing environment? Or am I unable to test this activity on 6.0 devices from now on?

Comment: Not confident enough in this info to give an official answer, but since `WRITE_SETTINGS` is a sensitive permission, you won't be able to grant it with `GrantPermissionRule`. You will likely end up needing to use [UIAutomator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator) in your tests to select the appropriate response in the [permissions management screen](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS).

Comment: @pushasha Yeah, I figured this might be the case. I'll start working on programaticly clicking through the permissions management screen but that thing looks different in some flavours of Android. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @pushasha You can create an answer for this, I'll accept it. `GrantPermissionRule` doesn't support signature permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `WRITE_SETTINGS` is a sensitive permission, you won't be able to grant it using `GrantPermissionRule` in API 23. You will likely end up needing to use [UIAutomator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator) in your tests to select the appropriate response in the [permissions management screen](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS).

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get around this by granting the permission using UiAutomator and the shell `appops` command:

```java
Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation();
UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(instrumentation);
String targetPackageName = instrumentation.getTargetContext().getPackageName();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    String shellCommand = String.format("appops set %s WRITE_SETTINGS allow", targetPackageName);
    device.executeShellCommand(shellCommand);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed to get the Android Test Device (ATD) working.